# Try to use in cin,peek()

Tags: c++

I try to get from the user inputs till blank line
so I wrote this:

```
while (c != '\n')
{
    c = cin.peek();
    cin >> check;
    if (check == "Test") 
    {
        cin >> ID >> One >> Two >> Three;
        Test[i++] = Test(ID, One, Two, Three);
    }
}
```

to example, I get from the user Test 12 45 56 78 99 now, check=test, id=45, one, 56, two=78, three=99
and when I enter empty line, why the while loop isn't stopped?

Comment: If you want a line at a time, then *get* a line at a time.  That's what `std::getline` is for.  You can use a `istringstream` to grab pieces of the line once you've seen it's not empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do; you don't use the
results of `cin.peek()` until far later, after having done
significantly more input, without testing whether it succeeded
or not.  Given the code, my first question is: do you understand
how `while` works?  Modifying the value of a control variable
within the loop will not cause you to break out of the loop; the
test is only done at the top of the loop.  And you must *always*
verify that input has succeeded before using the variables
you've input.

If your input is line oriented, the classical solution would
be:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, line ) && !isEmpty( line ) ) {
    std::istringstream parser( line );
    if ( parser >> check >> ID >> One >> Two >> Three >> std::ws
            && parser.get() == EOF ) {
        //  Data is good, can be used...
    } else {
        //  Some sort of format error in the line...
    }
}
```

I've put the test for an empty line in a separate function,
because you probably want to treat a line with just white space
as empty.  (Users may accidentally hit the space bar before
enter, and what they see will still look like an empty line.)
That's also why I `>>` into `std::ws` before checking that
there's no garbage at the end of line when parsing.

Comment: @BenVoigt Fixed, thanks.  I'm getting careless in my old age.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> check;
```

is a *formatted* input function, meaning it will discard leading white space.  A blank line is just leading white space, it will be discarded and the extraction operator will keep reading until non-whitespace data arrives, or an I/O error occurs.

Comment: The same goes for all of the following as well.  The real question is what he expected the `c = std::cin.peek()` to do.